# Finding if an object is in the range of a given number(positioning is in latitude and longitude)

Tags: algorithm, math, latitude-longitude

I have(for exemple) a hotel with the **latitude: 46.752879** and **longitude: 23.605848** and my position: **latitude 46.776073** and **longitude 23.605802**. I want to find out if the hotel is in 2km range from my position. How can I do that?

I read that 1 deg latitude=110.6 km so 46.752879=5,170(approximate) but how can i calculated the longitude? How would it be easier to find out if the hotel is in the range?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the [Haversine forumla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to compute (an approximation of) the distance between two points on the surface of a sphere.

Comment: What language are you using, if you are using any, to calculate the distance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)